# Unit Testing and Mac OS X 10.10.3 Language and Region Settings

Tags: java, macos, maven, locale

**THE CASE**

Without going much into details, `mvn test` fails on system with French language settings. In order to target that issue with regression testing, I want to create a regression test, which sets locale to French, and the runs unit tests with `Maven`.

I switch between English and French in `System Preferences > Language & Region > Advanced > Format language`.

**THE PROBLEM**

1. While on English locale, I check the settings with `locale`:

> ```
> LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_ALL=
> ```

2. Run `mvn test`, it passes
3. Switch to French locale with OS X GUI
4. Run `mvn test`, it fails (as expected)
5. Run `locale` in the same terminal - it still produces the same results as before (although it shouldn't, as I switched to French)
6. Open new terminal and run `locale`:

> ```
> LANG=
> LC_COLLATE="C"
> LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
> LC_MESSAGES="C"
> LC_MONETARY="C"
> LC_NUMERIC="C"
> LC_TIME="C"
> LC_ALL=
> ```

**THE FINDINGS**

For some reason, output of `locale` command corresponds to locale settings as of the time when the terminal was started. If you open up terminal, change locale via GUI and then run `locale` command, which won't be visible to this command.

Subsequently, if I amend locale by exporting `LC_ALL` or other variables of that kind, this does not actually change unit test results. If I change locale via GUI, it will.

**THE QUESTION**

How to change locale using command line, so that they are actually applied?

Comment: Locale is a group of env settings isn't it? Why not pass the environment settings as args to the maven command you run for your tests?

Comment: That's what doesn't work. LC_* settings seem to be a report of locale-specific system setting at the terminal launch time, rather than actual read/write settings. I tried setting locale before running maven and setting them at the same time, it is ignored.

Comment: How are you accessing locale in your program; through `java.util.Locale` or via `System.getenv()`?

Comment: I don't access them explicitly. They implicitly come into play when I call DecimalFormat with Double.valueOf etc - locale-specific decimal separator is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the locale which is used by DecimalFormat in a number of ways.

You can set the Locale returned by Locale.getDefault (which is used in DecimalFormat) by specifying some config to surefire in your pom. This would allow you to, for example, have several profiles each testing a different locale.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Duser.language=fr -Duser.region=FR</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or you could set what Locale.getDefault will return in your tests. In the below example there is a @Before/@After to revert the Locale.getDefault to its previous state so that the changing of defaultLocale does not impact other tests

```
public class LocaleTest {

    private Locale localeBefore;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        localeBefore = Locale.getDefault();
    }

    @After
    public void revertLocale() {
        Locale.setDefault(localeBefore);
    }

    @Test
    public void passesInFRFRLocale() {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
        assertThat(DecimalFormat.getInstance().format(1000.01D), is(equalTo("1 000,01")));
    }

    @Test
    public void passesInENGBLocale() {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK);
        assertThat(DecimalFormat.getInstance().format(1000.01D), is(equalTo("1,000.01")));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on how terminal works with OS X locale, although presents an ability to unit-test this piece of code. Therefore upvoting and leaving as unanswered.